# React-Native-iap getProducts() returns empty array

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase

*Version of react-native-iap*
**3.3.7**

*Version of react-native*
**0.60.4**

*Platforms you faced the error (IOS or Android or both?)*
**only on ios**

*Expected behavior*
**getProducts returns array of products**

*Actual behavior*
**returns empty array
it is working well on android**

*Tested environment (Emulator? Real Device?)*
**Emulator and Real Device**

*Addition*
**All in app purchase products were already approved in app store.
I also tried to use version 4.4.8, but no difference. :(
Please help me.**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When products aren't fetched, it's most likely some configuration issue. On iOS the most likely culprits are:

1. The products are not in the 'Ready To Submit' state (make sure you've added the screenshot).
2. You haven't signed your Paid Applications Agreement in App Store Connect
3. You're testing on an emulator instead of a physical device.

If your products were already approved, and you've tried on a physical device, I'd double check #2 and make sure you have the latest Paid Applications Agreement signed.

Here's a handy post on the topic from [RevenueCat](https://support.revenuecat.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041793174-Why-are-my-products-offerings-or-available-packages-empty-), some is RevenueCat specific but most of the checklist applies to any app.

Comment: Thank you 'enc_life'. 
My products were already approved, but I didn't sign Paid Applications agreement because my app is free. 
I have signed the Paid Applications agreement in App Store Connect. Then my products were fetched. It is working on both of emulator and physical device.

Comment: Updated link: https://community.revenuecat.com/sdks-51/why-are-offerings-or-products-empty-124

Comment: In my case i was missing no 2. Thanks

Comment: is there a way to test on the emulator as well? Apple mentioned [how we can do that using swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_in_xcode) but don't know how we can do it using *react-native-iap*

Answer (score 0):

This thread is long dead and solved. But so others won't need to spend weeks like I did, here is something I wish I had found on StackOverflow.

getProducts() doesn't get a list of products from the store. Given a list of product id's (SKUs) getProducts gets *details* about those products.

I was calling

```
getProducts();
```

But the proper way to call getProducts is something like this:

```
const skus = Platform.select({
     ios: ['product_id_ios'],
     android: ['product_id_android'],
});
getProducts({skus});
```

I hope this helps somebody

Comment: hi, is the product_id_ios the product ID you names it in apple connect?

Comment: @hugger, yep that's right. It is unfortunate that this is the way getProducts() works because if you want to add a new item to the store you have to change your code rather then just populating based on what apple provides.

Answer (score 0):

if someone still banging there head after following all 3 steps mentioned by @enc_life, following above 3 steps are must.

make sure you are calling getproducts from 'react-native-iap' only by importing it instead of using hooks.

```
import {initConnection,getProducts,} from 'react-native-iap';

const skus = [
 'com.iaptest.onetimepurchase', //consumable
  'com.iaptest.purchaseagain',  // non-consumable
];

useEffect(() => {
const rniapInitiate = async () => {
  try {
    await initConnection()
    const productResult = await getProducts({skus});
    console.log('productResult:', productResult);
    if (productResult.length > 0){
      setRetrievedProducts(productResult)
    } 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('the error:', error);
  }
};

rniapInitiate();

}, []);
```

if you still struggling with empty array you may have one such issues mentioned over in [here](https://react-native-iap.dooboolab.com/docs/guides/troubleshooting)